# Does PHP require, require_once, or include automatically read the file at page load?

Tags: php, include, require, require-once

I have several pages which use the include or require language constructs within PHP. Many of these lie within IF, ELSE statements.

I do realize that a page will not load at all if a require'd file is missing but the main purpose of including this way is to:

1) reduce code clutter on the page

2) not load the file unless a statement is met.

Does issuing an include or require statement load the file regardless (and thus eliminating the benefits I was trying to achieve by placing within the if/else statement?

Brief example:

```
<?php


$i = 1

if($i ==1) {

      require_once('somefile.php');

} else {

     require_once('otherfile.php');
}

?>
```

At page load, are both files checked AND loaded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you place an `include`/`require` statement in the body of an `if` *(or `else`)*, it'll be executed if the `if`'s condition is true.

```
if ($a == 10) {
    // your_first_file.php will only be loaded if $a == 10
    require 'your_first_file.php';
} else {
    // your_second_file.php will only be loaded if $a != 10
    require 'your_second_file.php';
}
```

And, if you want, you can test this pretty easily.

This first example :

```
if (true) {
    require 'file_that_doesnt_exist';
}
```

will get you :

```
Warning: require(file_that_doesnt_exist) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'file_that_doesnt_exist'
```

i.e. the `require` is executed -- and fails, as the file doesn't exist.

While this second example :

```
if (false) {
    require 'file_that_doesnt_exist';
}
```

Will not get you any error : the `require` is not executed.

Comment: Hahahaha! Pascal Martin is at it again - with excellent and detailed input, as always. :) +1 for showing how to test it

Answer (score 4):

> At page load, are both files checked AND loaded?

No, at least not since (IIRC) PHP 4.0.1.

If you want to reduce include clutter, and you are working with mainly object-oriented code, also take a look at PHP's [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: thanks! I just didn't want to waste unnecessary resources and have always wondered

Comment: Whee are some good reasons against autoloading - most related to bytecode caches.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I don't follow your reasoning (well, there isn't any). I use APC with enabled opcode cache and my applications usually make heavy use of autoloading, but I never had any problems with it. What am I doing wrong? What should I do to get problems?

Comment: I don't remember what exactly caused it.. but I think I read about it here on SO so a search might help.

Comment: Autoloaders and opcode caches used to not get along.  This is no longer the case in modern PHP (since the realpath cache was created), though poorly-designed autoloaders can cause more filesystem poking and prodding than strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

No, only one of those files would be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The `include` and `require` constructs are only evaluated when passed. The files are only read when your expression is met.

It's simple to explain by considering that the constructs might contain variables:

```
require_once("otherfile-{$i}.php");
```

That's supported. But it could not possibly work before PHP runs over that particular line, because it needs to know the state of `$i` to load the right file.

Comment: Hopefully someone copies you scripty and replaces the `{$i}` with a `{$_GET['i']}` :D (Yes, I am evil, hehehe)

Comment: Your advises will yield you an unpleasant afterlife.

Comment: Oh, who knows. Probably you just need to say `' OR 1 --` just before they send you to hell and you'll magically land in paradise ;) +1